# what does .seek means in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, windows

what is the purpose of `f.seek(0)` in this script? Why do we need to `rewind(current_file)`, if the file has already been opened by the program?

```
input_file = ARGV[0]

def print_all(f)
    puts f.read()
end

def rewind(f)
    f.seek(0)
end

def print_a_line(line_count,f)
puts "#{line_count} #{f.readline()}"
end

current_file = File.open(input_file)

puts "First Let's print the whole file:"
puts # a blank line

print_all(current_file)

puts "Now Let's rewind, kind of like a tape"

rewind(current_file)

puts "Let's print the first line:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-seek

Comment: It's **inside** a method called `rewind`, doesn't that give you a hint? If not, couldn't you read the docs?

Comment: i finished i solve it thanks anyways

Comment: You need to get in the habit of searching the documentation first. Go to http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/ or http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/ and search, or open a terminal window on your machine and type `ri seek`.

Comment: People seem to think that just because there is an "explanation" on the web, such as the Ruby docs, that it automatically makes sense to a noob. This is not the case. I am currently working on this very same problem, having the very same question. I hit the docs (appearing 1st on Google) and it made no sense to me whatsoever. This post was 2nd in SERPs. What's even more amazing is that the SO gnomes close the topic, once again proving that SO is not for noobs. Thanks goes to @Nikolai Manek for taking the time to answer instead of being a stereotypical SO AH.

Comment: https://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex20.html

Answer (score 23):

It seeks ("goes to", "attempts to find") a given position (as integer) in a stream. In your code you define a new method called `rewind` which takes one argument. When you call it with

```
rewind(current_file)
```

you send the current_file (the one you have opened from disk or from anywhere else) which is defined as:

```
current_file = File.open(input_file)
```

to the rewind method and it will "seek" to position 0 which is the beginning of the file.

You could also create another method called `almost_rewind` and write:

```
def almost_rewind(f)
  f.seek(-10, IO::SEEK_END)
end
```

This would go 10 positions backwards in your stream, starting from the END of the stream.

Comment: Thanks Nikolai, for being the only one with enough integrity to answer. Your answer is infinitely clearer than the Ruby docs. If only more SOers were like you.

Comment: If only the Ruby docs were written to be read by people who don't already know the answers.

Comment: `f.seek(-10)` or passing even `-1` always generates: `Invalid argument @ rb_io_seek - test.txt (Errno::EINVAL)`

Comment: After looking at: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-seek I believe, something like: `f.seek(-10, IO::SEEK_CUR)` would work. When using negative values, you have to give it a starting point (in this case current position) to move back from. If it's a single arg, then it must be a positive 'real' character position.

Comment: @codeFinity - Yes, I updated my example with SEEK::END. You are right:)